# Use TagAwareAdapter per config.yml in Symfony 3.2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am aware that I can define a cache in Symfony 3.2 like that in my config.yml:

```
    cache:
    default_redis_provider: redis://%redis_password%@%redis_host%:%redis_port%
    pools:
        my_redis_cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.redis
            public: true
            default_lifetime: 1200
            provider: cache.default_redis_provider
```

E.g. in my Controller I can simple use

```
$cache = $this->get('my_redis_cache');
```

Now since Symfony 3.2 we have a fantastic new feature called [TagAwareAdapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html#tag-aware-adapters) - which allows cache invalidation by tags.

This is done in code by:

```
$cache = new TagAwareAdapter(
// Adapter for cached items
new FilesystemAdapter(),
// Adapter for tags
new RedisAdapter('redis://localhost')
);
```

But could I define it in my config.yml?

I am looking for something like:

```
    cache:
    default_redis_provider: redis://%redis_password%@%redis_host%:%redis_port%
    pools:
        my_redis_cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.redis
            public: true
            default_lifetime: 1200
            provider: cache.default_redis_provider
        my_tag_aware_cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.tagawareadapter
            provider:
                - my_file_cache
                - my_redis_cache
```

But I have no idea how to define it - I am playing try & error since a while now - all I got was error so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupid me. I could do it by defining a simple service in `services.yml`:

```
    my_tag_aware_cache:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter
        arguments: [ '@my_file_cache', '@my_redis_cache' ]
```

Now I receive my cache in controller with

```
$cache = $this->get('my_tag_aware_cache');
```

and it's a TagAware Cache.

Or is there another/better way to achieve this?

Comment: do you know if there is a config only solution? I think it's a bit strange that `CacheItem` does allow setting of tags but tags are only working when using a `TagAwareAdapter`. And a `TagAwareAdapter` must be created manually.

Comment: sorry, don't fully get your question, my solution is 'config-only' when you mean no new ... statements in my code

Answer (score 5):

The upper answer provides the ***solution*** and its a good one, I'll just put it all together as an answer, as I also wasted some time finding out how to use the TagAwareAdapter.  This is my solution for Symfony 3.4.

**config.yml**

```
cache:
    pools:
        app.cache.file:
            public: true
            adapter: cache.adapter.filesystem
        app.cache.redis:
            public: true
            adapter: cache.adapter.redis
```

**services.yml**:

```
myapp.cache:
    public: true
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter
    arguments: [ '@app.cache.file', '@app.cache.redis' ]
```

The use it like this(eg in Controller):

```
/** @var TagAwareAdapterInterface $cache */
$cache = $this->get('myapp.cache');
```

Don't forget to have a redis instance in place and install redis package:

```
composer require predis/predis
```